# To Implement these ListActivity to display videos in url

Tags: android, video, android-intent, android-listview

I need to implement these ListActivity.java

**ListActivity.java:**

```
package com.sit.fth.activity;

public class ListActivity extends Activity {
    private ListView lv;
    private String[] groupArray = {"Category1", "Category2", "Category3"};
    private String[][] childArray = {{"Test Greater glory Part-3","Greater glory Part-1"},
        {"What does","SundayService ( 19_01_14 )"}, {"Greater glory Part-3", "SundayService ( 19_01_14 )Tamil"}};

    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.list1);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

        String[] data = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("strArray");
        AdapterView.OnItemClickListener clickListener = null;

        // If no data received means this is the first activity
        if (data == null) {
            data = groupArray;
            clickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ListActivity.this, ListActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("strArray", childArray[position]);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            };
        }

        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(clickListener);

     }

}
```

**list1.java:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

If I click the `Category1` in that ListView.Another ListView shown.

My problem is,If I click the `TestGreater Glory Part-3`, the video have to display from URL.I doesn't know how to implement that `ListActivity` Class to the below codings.

**strings.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <string name="str_video">VIDEO</string>
<string name="api_host">URL Here</string>

</resources>
```

**YouTubePlayActivity.java:**

```
package com.sit.fth.activity;

public class YoutubePlayActivity extends YouTubeFailureRecoveryActivity {
    public static final String DEVELOPER_KEY = "DEVELOPER_KEY_HERE";
    private String videoId;
    private YouTubePlayerView youTubeView;
    private ActionBar actionabar;
    private int position;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
        super.onCreate(arg0);

        setContentView(R.layout.youtube_play);

        position = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("position");

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        videoId = bundle.getString("videoid");

        FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
        youTubeView = new YouTubePlayerView(this);
        frameLayout.addView(youTubeView);
        youTubeView.initialize(DEVELOPER_KEY, this);

        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.header_title)).setText(bundle
                .getString("title"));

        actionabar = getActionBar();
        //actionabar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        actionabar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
            YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
        if (!wasRestored) {
            try {
                if (videoId != null) {
                    // 2GPfZYwYZoQ
                    player.cueVideo(videoId);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Not a Valid Youtube Video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Not a Valid Youtube Video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
        return youTubeView;
    }
}
```

I need to implement that `ListActivity.java` Class to get the videos shown in the url.

Comment: What is the problem? How to show it? It don't start? It fails to read values from json?

Comment: @MarcoAcierno If I click that `Test Greater Glory part-3` in listView.The video have to load from these http://tfhapp.fathershouse.in/api/video.php php link with the same name `Test Greater Glory part-3`.

Comment: So clickListener will be null when the user select the category, you don't know how to implement the other things from here?

Comment: @MarcoAcierno yes,I doesn't have an idea.I am an android beginner.thats why I set a bounty for these.

Comment: I understand this: The user join in Activity 1 where appears all the category, then after click in a category it will open the video list (which is coded inside the application and not from json) it clicks in a video so you should open the YoutubePlayActivity and play the video, right? When the video class is used? I would start with implement Parcelable to Video and pass this object to YoutubePlayActivity and the activity will have all the informations it needs. Then, the second adapter could be <Video> instead of <String> so we know which object to pass to the Activity

Comment: But in the Main activity we don't have video, when Video is filled with all the informations? You could make it a bit more flexible by loading the Category/Films from JSON and not hardcode it inside the application. If you don't want to do it, you should iterate over all videos to do something and check..

Comment: @MarcoAcierno I edited and posted `HomeActivity.java`.esp these `HomeActivity.java` is my MainActivity Class.Then I posted `VideoAdapter.java` also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an app that lists categories (*that you provide*). After clicking some category, it's videos will be loaded from the `JSON` file and displayed as another `ListView`.

When you click on a video, it's `url and title` is sent to the `YoutubeActivity`. YoutubeActivity then starts a player with that video.

I believe you wanted something more complex but you can add the other functionality (such as getting additional fields from the json) quite easily. If you would want to import categories also, then you'd need *another json structure* such as `array of categories`->`array of videos`.

**ListActivity:**

```
package com.example.youtubecatplayer;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
/**
 * Created by Simon on 2014 Jul 08.
 */
public class ListActivity extends Activity {
    // Categories must be pre-set
    private String[] data = {"Category1", "Category2", "Category3"};
    private final String JSONUrl = "http://tfhapp.fathershouse.in/api/video.php";
    private final String TAG_VIDEOS = "videos";
    private final String TAG_CAT = "video_category";
    private final String TAG_URL = "video_url";
    private final String TAG_TITLE = "video_title";

    private List<String> videoTitles = new ArrayList<String>();
    private List<String> videoURLs = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayAdapter adapter;

    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.list1);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        AdapterView.OnItemClickListener clickListener = null;

        // Category view:
        if (extras == null) {
            clickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ListActivity.this, ListActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("categoryName", data[position]);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            };
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
        }
        else { // Child view
            // Get the category of this child
            String categoryName = extras.getString("categoryName");
            if (categoryName == null)
                finish();

            // Populate list with videos of "categoryName", by looping JSON data
            new JSONParse(categoryName).execute();

            clickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ListActivity.this, YoutubeActivity.class);
                    // Send video url and title to YoutubeActivity
                    intent.putExtra("videoUrl", videoURLs.get(position));
                    intent.putExtra("videoTitle", videoTitles.get(position));
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            };
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, videoTitles);
        }

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(clickListener);
    }

    private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        private String categoryName;

        // Constructor // Get the categoryName of which videos will be found
        public JSONParse(String category) {
            this.categoryName = category;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a loading dialog when getting the videos
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ListActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Getting Videos...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
            // Get JSON from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONUrl);
            if (json == null)
                return null;

            try {
                // Get video array
                JSONArray videos = json.getJSONArray(TAG_VIDEOS);

                // Loop all videos
                for (int i=0; i<videos.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject video = videos.getJSONObject(i);
                    Log.e("JSON:", "cat: "+video.getString(TAG_CAT)+",title: "+video.getString(TAG_TITLE)+", url: "+video.getString(TAG_URL));
                    // Check if video belongs to "categoryName"
                    if (video.getString(TAG_CAT).equals(categoryName)) {
                        addVideo(video);
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return json;
        }

        private void addVideo(JSONObject video) {
            try {
                // Add title and URL to their respective arrays
                videoTitles.add(video.getString(TAG_TITLE));
                videoURLs.add(video.getString(TAG_URL));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
            // Close the "loading" dialog
            pDialog.dismiss();
            if (json == null) {
                // Do something when there's no internet connection
                // Or there are no videos to be displayed
            }
            else // Let the adapter notify ListView that it has new items
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
// Example JSON video item
// {"videoid":"59","video_type":"Youtube","language":"english","date":"08 Jul 2014",
// "video_title":"What does","video_category":"Category2","video_url":"P84FGn49b4A"},
```

**YoutubeActivity:**

```
package com.example.youtubecatplayer;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView;
/**
 * Created by Simon on 2014 Jul 08.
 */
public class YoutubeActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener{
    public static final String DEVELOPER_KEY = "DEV_KEY";
    private String videoId;
    private ActionBar actionabar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
        super.onCreate(arg0);
        setContentView(R.layout.youtube_activity);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        videoId = bundle.getString("videoUrl");
        this.setTitle(bundle.getString("videoTitle"));
        //((TextView) findViewById(R.id.videoTitle)).setText(bundle.getString("videoTitle"));

        YouTubePlayerView playerView = (YouTubePlayerView)findViewById(R.id.youtubeplayerview);
        playerView.initialize(DEVELOPER_KEY, this);

        actionabar = getActionBar();
        //actionabar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        actionabar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,
                                        boolean wasRestored) {
        if (!wasRestored) {
            try {
                if (videoId != null) {
                    // 2GPfZYwYZoQ
                    player.cueVideo(videoId);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Not a Valid Youtube Video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Not a Valid Youtube Video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                        YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
    }
}
```

**JSONParser:**

```
package com.example.youtubecatplayer;
/**
 * Created by Simon on 2014 Jul 08.
 */
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.util.Log;
public class JSONParser {
    public JSONParser() {
    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {
        InputStream input = null;
        String jsonStr = null;
        JSONObject jsonObj = null;
        try {
            // Make the request
            input = new URL(url).openStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input,
                    Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            int ch;
            while ((ch = reader.read()) != -1)
                strBuilder.append((char) ch);

            input.close();
            jsonStr = strBuilder.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
        // return JSON String
        return jsonObj;
    }
}
```

NOTE: you need internet permission in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

And you need to implement the YoutubeAPI into your project.

1. [Download YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/)
2. build.gradle `compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')`

EDIT:

I just tried to re-create this project and it worked perfectly. Here's my layout and manifest files, maybe they're causing you trouble.

**Android Manifest:**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.simas.myapplication" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".ListActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".YoutubeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**youtube_activity.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
        android:id="@+id/youtubeplayerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**list1.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".ListActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Don't forget to change the developer key, or you will see a player initialization problem.**

Comment: just before I am implemented your code.I am getting the videos asusually.Firstly I doesn't get the ListView.Thats my problem.

Comment: There's no more VideoFragment, i skipped that out. ListActivity displays categories, *onClick* then videos and then *onClick* goes to YoutubePlayActivity to display the video. Join the [Chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56952/help-stephen) and explain your problem further.

Comment: I tried your answer in many ways but it doesn't show the ListView.Output shows a blank screen in video tab.

Comment: @Stephen I updated my answer, re-tested and confirmed that it works.

Comment: I can't help you when you are not even starting ListActivity as your main activity. I provided the code, that works. It's your job to implement it into your application, sorry.

Comment: as you said to use a mainactivity as a ListActivity.I got a output.Everyhing would be shown perrfectly.But I doesn't get the category list in Video Tab.Hope so I can get it soon.Thank you for all your help :)

Comment: Simon, I am glad. you helped me.and also you are a nice person just be calm and wrote up more codes for me.No words to express about it.